# Select2 on change event is not working in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, jquery-select2

I was working with select2 in vuejs , I found vuejs is not working with jquery select2 as vuejs is working with navite html.

I am using this code

```js
Vue.directive('select', {
        twoWay: true,
        bind: function () {
            $(this.el).select2()
            .on("select2:select", function(e) {
                this.set($(this.el).val());
            }.bind(this));
            },
        update: function(nv, ov) {
            $(this.el).trigger("change");
        }
    });
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        supplier_id: "niklesh"
      }
    })
    $('#supplier_id').select2({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.css">
<div id="app">
  {{ supplier_id }}

<select id="supplier_id" class='form-control' v-model='supplier_id' v-select='supplier_id'>
    <option value="atul">Atul</option>
    <option value="niklesh">Niklesh</option>
    <option value="sachin">Sachin</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Please share your reply to handle this problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get this to work with a directive, we need to understand how `v-model` works. From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events):

> ```
> <input v-model="something">
> ```
>
> is just syntactic sugar for:
>
> ```
> <input v-bind:value="something" v-on:input="something = $event.target.value">
> ```

In the case of a select element, `v-model` will listen for the `change` event (not `input`). So, if the directive dispatches a `change` event when the element changes, then `v-model` will work as expected.

Here is an updated version of your code (works in Vue 2):

```js
Vue.directive('select', {
  twoWay: true,
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    $(el).select2().on("select2:select", (e) => {
      // v-model looks for
      //  - an event named "change"
      //  - a value with property path "$event.target.value"
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { target: e.target }));
    });
  },
  componentUpdated: function(el, me) {
    // update the selection if the value is changed externally
    $(el).trigger("change");
  }
});
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    supplier_id: "niklesh"
  },
})
$('#supplier_id').select2({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.css">
<div id="app">
  {{ supplier_id }}

  <select id="supplier_id" class='form-control' v-model='supplier_id' v-select='supplier_id'>
    <option value="atul">Atul</option>
    <option value="niklesh">Niklesh</option>
    <option value="sachin">Sachin</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

And here's a version that works in Vue 3 (custom directives have different syntax, [linked here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-directives.html#custom-directives)):

```js
var app = Vue.createApp({
  data: function() { 
    return {
      supplier_id: "niklesh"
    }
  }
})

app.directive('select', {
  beforeMount: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    $(el).select2().on("select2:select", (e) => {
      // v-model looks for
      //  - an event named "change"
      //  - a value with property path "$event.target.value"
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { target: e.target }));
    });
  },
    updated: function(el) {
    // update the selection if the value is changed externally
    $(el).trigger("change");
  }
});

app.mount('#app');

$('#supplier_id').select2({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.11"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.css">
<div id="app">
  {{ supplier_id }}

  <select id="supplier_id" class='form-control' v-model='supplier_id' v-select='supplier_id'>
    <option value="atul">Atul</option>
    <option value="niklesh">Niklesh</option>
    <option value="sachin">Sachin</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I am using a multi-select, so I also had to trigger the change event on `select2:unselect`, like this:

`$(el).select2().on("select2:select select2:unselect", (e) => {`

Comment: This doen't seem to work with Vue3. Any ideas why?

Comment: @e4rthdog Directives work differently in Vue 3. I added a code snippet for Vue 3.

Answer (score 10):

By assigning select2 value to vuejs data I am able to fix this problem. I didn't use custom directive here.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    supplier_id: "niklesh"
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function (value) {
      if (!value) return ''
      value = value.toString()
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
    }
  }
});

$('#supplier_id').on("change",function(){
    app.supplier_id = $(this).val();
    console.log('Name : '+$(this).val());
});

$('#supplier_id').select2({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.css">
<div id="app">
  Name : {{ supplier_id | capitalize }}
<select id="supplier_id" class='form-control' v-model='supplier_id'>
    <option value="atul">Atul</option>
    <option value="niklesh">Niklesh</option>
    <option value="sachin">Sachin</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Please comment if this is not good way or any better solution you suggest.

Comment: asked AND answered 1 minute ago?

Comment: @darryn.ten: This is my own answer, although its works through jquery but I would be great if I can solve this through vuejs.

Comment: @Rishi: I don't think this is a bad solution, but your original idea of using a directive seems more reusable. I've added a solution showing how you could use a directive instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select v-model="selected">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
</select>


const self = this;
$("select").change(function () {
        const val = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        self.selected = val;
 });
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by providing an explanation as to why it works, and why it is a better approach than the accepted answer.

Comment: The easiest and simplest solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `v-on:change="onChange"` in your select control

**HTML template**

```
<select id="supplier_id" class='form-control' 
v-model='supplier_id' v-select='supplier_id' v-on:change="onChange">
    <option value="atul">Atul</option>
    <option value="niklesh">Niklesh</option>
    <option value="sachin">Sachin</option>
</select>
```

"onChange" is the name of your method

**JavaScript**

```
methods: {
  onChange(e) {        
      alert("Change");   
  }
}
```