# How to use v-model and other js plugins in the same select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-select2, vuejs2

I am using jquery **select2** and **datepicker** plugins in my project. I have used custom directives for them. They work fine until I need to get the selected value using `v-model`. For some reason, it does not bind the value. My guess is that there is a conflict somewhere.

Here is my directive:

```
Vue.directive('select', {
    twoWay: true,
    inserted: function (el) {
        $(el).select2();
    },
    updated: function (el) {
        $(el).select2();
    }
});
```

The **updated** function doesn't work. But **inserted** works.

How can I get the selected value?

Comment: Check this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/q/40973841/2815635

Answer (score 2):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#twoWay-Prop-Option-removed

> `twoWay` Prop Option removed
>
> Props are now always one-way down. To produce side effects in the
> parent scope, a component needs to explicitly emit an event instead of
> relying on implicit binding.

You will need to write a [wrapper component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html). As it happens, the example is for select2.