# Vue conditional rendering

Tags: vue.js, jquery-select2

I am using Vuejs. I have a select input with multiple select and select2 class.

```
<select class="select 2" v-if="show" multiple><option>1</option></select>
```

Initially show will be `false`, so that the element will not rendered.
I just want to get the select 2 property for this select element which actually not triggering.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried already and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: use v-show="show", v-if does not render your select element if 'show' is false

Comment: html:<select class="select 2" v-if="show" multiple><option>1</option></select> <script >$(".select2").select2()</script>. And in the vue there is method which changes the show to true.

Comment: @M.Suurland even if I am using v-show there are other situations, like if this select is inside a div which uses v-for and the object in v-for is empty , the same problem again comes. So is there any solution for this dynamic rendering element

Comment: You need a [wrapper component](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html).

Comment: Do you have some sample code to explain more? If you use a v-show instead of a v-if the element will be actually inserted, which might help you get a reference to it... but I'm not clear on what you're trying to do

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40973841/2815635

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic solution, which does not cover value binding.

For the complete solution use the provided [select2 wrapper](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html?redirect=true)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: false,
    values: []
  },
  watch: {
    show(val) {
      if (val) {
        var vm = this;
        Vue.nextTick(function () {        
          $(".select2").select2();
        })        
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  line-height: 1.75;
}

[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
select {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  Show: <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="show">
  <span class="slider"></span>
  </label><br/>
  <div v-if="show">
    <select class="select2" v-model="values" multiple>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/select2@4.0.3/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/select2@4.0.3/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
```