# this.$root.$emit run the event twice

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jquery-select2

I'm starting to work with `vue.js` and for my project I saw the need to use the following `select2` wrapper component from the official site of vue.js this is the link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html the problem is that I need to issue a root event at the moment to change the value of the select2 that is why it adds a line of code in the following part:

```
.on('change', function () {
  vm.$emit('input', this.value);
  vm.$root.$emit('eventing', this.value);
})
```

this works, but I realized from the console of vue, that my event was broadcast 2 times, I thought it was my code problem and remove the line that added, but the input event was also issued twice, my question: is this normal behavior? Is it a bad practice to do this? There is something that I am missing. For me it is a problem that is issued twice since since my event I am making an ajax call and it is executed twice the same.

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim 
Hi, I'm using the same code as the link you provide, and just increase that line of code to issue an event by changing the value of the select, and I have another single file component where I hear the event, with this reproduction you can get an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/d131Lebj/5634/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 on change event is not working in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973841/select2-on-change-event-is-not-working-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to bind data to select2 with vue:

```
Vue.directive('select', {
  twoWay: true,
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
      $(el).select2().on("select2:select", (e) => {
        // v-model looks for
        //  - an event named "change"
        //  - a value with property path "$event.target.value"
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { target: e.target }));
    });
  },
 });
```

This bind to all the select's on the Vue instance so that they work with v-model and you can use select2

After, add v-model="" and v-select="" to your  that is being targeted by select2, and you're set.

Credit to: [Select2 on change event is not working in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973841/select2-on-change-event-is-not-working-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off in beforeDestroy...

```js
beforeDestroy() {
  this.$root.$off('change', yourFunction)
},
```